# Why fail to assign value to a blank position in a dataframe, returns "replacement has 1 row, data has 0 row"

Tags: r

I have a list, whose elements are data frames. For those data frames, there exist some missing value. I don't want to leave them blank, therefore I wrote a loop to assign "AAAAA" to the blank positions. But it returns

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name",  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

The data frame has 0 row

```
list(Teaching_Hospital_ID = character(0), teaching_hospital_name = character(0), 
    physician_primary_type = character(0), physician_specialty = character(0), 
    recipient_zip_code = character(0), total_amount_of_payment_usdollars = numeric(0), 
    submitting_applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_name = character(0), 
    applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name = character(0), 
    date_of_payment = character(0), recipient_state = character(0), 
    physician_last_name = character(0), physician_first_name = character(0), 
    totalpayment = numeric(0))
```

My code is (DATA is that list)

```
for (i in 1:length(DATA)) {
  if(isTRUE(length(DATA[[i]]$applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name) == 0)) {
    DATA[[i]]$applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name <- "AAAAA"
  }
}
```

I am wondering why this error occurs and how to fix it

Comment: Does *"blank"* mean 0 or non-existing? Either way, your `if` condition is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: well, blank means "length(0)"

Comment: How does dataframe column have length 0? Consider adding 1 or 2 small example dataframes to your post.

Comment: > is.data.frame(DATA[[1]])
         [1] TRUE
> length(DATA[[1]]$applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name)
        [1] 0

Comment: 0 indicates that the column does not exist which is different from *"column has blank values"*. Anyways, it'd be easier to help if you add 1 or 2 small example dataframes to your post.

Comment: No need. Just add the output of `dput(lapply(DATA[1:2], head))` to your post.

Comment: I use "nrow(DATA[[1]]" to check that dataframe, it returns 0. So, I probably didn't make myself clear. It is a zero row dataframe. And I just want to assign some value to one column

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense. Are specifically only targeting dataframe with 0 rows? If so, use `DATA[[i]][1, "applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name"] <- "AAAAA"`

Comment: Yes, I am just targeting 0 row dataframe in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, here's a simpler way using `lapply` -

```
DATA <- lapply(DATA, function(x) {
  if(nrow(x) == 0) {
    x[1, "applicable_manufacturer_or_applicable_gpo_making_payment_name"] <- "AAAAA"
  }
  x
})
```